# How do I persist a file on a rpm update?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I am writing a rpm spec file and I want to persist a db file during an update.
I was reading the documentation and so far I found the `%config` modifier that persist configuration files.It is to say something like:

```
%file
%config(noreplace) foo.db
```

Is this the right way to persist a file during a rpm update?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, but you need to use full pathname to `foo.db`. Note that the previous version of your package, if not configured this way, will remove `foo.db` upon cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

Directive %ghost.

Files marked as ghost are not shipped in RPM. They are not being installed, but they are owned by package.

You still need to create them in %install. But touching is fine. So:

```
%install
touch %buildroot/var/foo

%files
%ghost /var/foo
```

This is intended for db files, log files etc.

Comment: It is not so clear for my what is the expected behavior of a ghost file during an update. Is it possible to combine %config and %ghost?

Comment: %config needs file info like st_mtime and file content digests to detect "changed". %ghost (in metadata) isn't a file, only a path with owner:group. So the answer is "no, you cannot mix %config and %ghost: there is no way to detect changed."

Comment: %ghost will also remove content when erased. this is likely surprising for persisted database content. Think carefully before using %ghost to persist a database file using %ghost: caveat emptor.